# How to create a modal window in angular with Kendo UI having the same functionality as Bootstrap modal has?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I have been googling for a while to find answers for my question. I have been decided that in my app I'm going to use Kendo UI as much as possible. I'm trying to reduce the number of different components in my app. But Kendo and its modal...

What I want it is a modal window where I can manipulate the data structure and after saving it will be reloaded and the grid will display the modified dataset. It is easily can be achieved by Bootstrap modal window and the service behind it.

I cannot see how can I achieve this using Kendo UI and angular:
 - I always see in the examples that jQuery and Angular are mixed - it is not my way. I have standards! ;)
 - I cannot see how the order of events are provided in Kendo's world. I mean when I click on the modal window save and close button the event order looks like this: window closed, data saved and grid reloaded.

Do you know any articles, blog entries where a noob like me can find answers? Telerik's documentation, especially angular related, is not easy to use.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the editable property in your Kendo UI Grid settings:

```
editable: "popup"
```

Answer (score 0):

correct me if im wrong but I think the proper syntax should be:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  editable: {
    mode: "popup"
  }
```